# How to setup Auth0 with custom domain on Nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js, auth0

I already have Auth0 working with my Nuxt.js application but now I'm trying to use it with a custom domain.

I already have everything set up and working on Auth0 side with a custom domain.

I tried to just change the domain on nuxt.config.js:

```
  auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/auth/login',
      callback: '/auth/signed-in'
    },
    fullPathRedirect: true,
    strategies: {
      local: false,
      auth0: {
        domain: 'customlogin.com',
        client_id: '------'
      }
    }
  }
```

But when I try to login I get this error from Auth0:

> You should not be hitting this endpoint. Make sure to use the code
>   snippets shown in the tutorial or visit support.auth0.com for help.

Auth0 also mention to add this to the configuration:

```
  overrides: {
    __tenant: config.auth0Tenant,
    __token_issuer: config.authorizationServer.issuer
  },
```

But I'm not sure where could I add this on NuxtJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the issue.
As I was using a custom login page on Auth0 settings, the additional setting above I had to add it there:

```
/* additional configuration needed for custom domains */
configurationBaseUrl: config.clientConfigurationBaseUrl,
overrides: {
  __tenant: config.auth0Tenant, 
  __token_issuer: 'custom.domain.com'
},
```